# Python too slow to find text in string in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, for-loop, nlp

I want to ***improve the loop performance*** where it counts word occurrences in text, but it runs ***around 5 minutes for 5 records now***

DataFrame

```
No                  Text   
1     I love you forever...*500 other words
2     No , i know that you know xxx *100 words
```

My word list

```
wordlist =['i','love','David','Mary',......]
```

My code to count word

```
for i in wordlist :
    df[i] = df['Text'].str.count(i)
```

Result :

```
No   Text                  I    love  other_words
 1    I love you ...       1      1      4
 2    No, i know ...       1      0      5
```

Comment: Your program doesn't count words, it counts occurrences. So for example "love" will be found in the string "a clover leaf". To efficiently count words, preprocess each Text by extracting the words, and using a `collections.Counter` which can be used to count the occurrences of any particular word efficiently.

Comment: thank for your comment. by the way, do you know how to improve the for loop in this context ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by making a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the words in each `Text` value, then converting that into columns (using `pd.Series`), summing the columns that don't exist in `wordlist` into `other_words` and then dropping those columns:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

wordlist = list(map(str.lower, wordlist))
counters = df['Text'].apply(lambda t:Counter(re.findall(r'\b[a-z]+\b', t.lower())))
df = pd.concat([df, counters.apply(pd.Series).fillna(0).astype(int)], axis=1)
other_words = list(set(df.columns) - set(wordlist) - { 'No', 'Text' })
df['other_words'] = df[other_words].sum(axis=1) 
df = df.drop(other_words, axis=1)
```

Output (for the sample data in your question):

```
   No                                 Text  i  love  other_words
0   1    I love you forever... other words  1     1            4
1   2  No , i know that you know xxx words  1     0            7
```

Note:

- I've converted all the words to lower-case so you're not counting `I` and `i` separately.
- I've used `re.findall` rather than the more obvious `split()` so that `forever...` gets counted as the word `forever` rather than `forever...`

If you only want to count the words in `wordlist` (and don't want an `other_words` count), you can simplify this to:

```
wordlist = list(map(str.lower, wordlist))
counters = df['Text'].apply(lambda t:Counter(w for w in re.findall(r'\b[a-z]+\b', t.lower()) if w in wordlist))
df = pd.concat([df, counters.apply(pd.Series).fillna(0).astype(int)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   No                                 Text  i  love
0   1    I love you forever... other words  1     1
1   2  No , i know that you know xxx words  1     0
```

Another way of also generating the `other_words` value is to generate 2 sets of counters, one of all the words, and one only of the words in `wordlist`. These can then be subtracted from each other to find the count of words in the text which are not in the wordlist:

```py
wordlist = list(map(str.lower, wordlist))
counters = df['Text'].apply(lambda t:Counter(w for w in re.findall(r'\b[a-z]+\b', t.lower()) if w in wordlist))
df = pd.concat([df, counters.apply(pd.Series).fillna(0).astype(int)], axis=1)
c2 = df['Text'].apply(lambda t:Counter(re.findall(r'\b[a-z]+\b', t.lower())))
df['other_words'] = (c2 - counters).apply(lambda d:sum(d.values()))
```

Output of this is the same as for the first code sample. Note that in Python 3.10 and later, you should be able to use the new `total` function:

```py
(c2 - counters).apply(Counter.total)
```

Comment: @foy no worries - I'm glad I could help. An interesting question...

Comment: but how wordlist  relate to counters and df, seems i can't find it is assigned/declared by other codes

Comment: @foy I'm not sure what you mean? I am taking the `wordlist` from your question, then I use it to figure out which words from the Counters are `other_words`  using this: `list(set(df.columns) - set(wordlist) - { 'No', 'Text' })`

Comment: refer back to original where i want item in the wordlist to be counted and assigned as a new column with the word name, e.g. df['love'] = <count love in text>,  how counter = to do such function here ? thanks

Comment: The `counters` variable is a series of `Counter`s (see the link in the question) which counts all the words in each `Text` value. By using `apply(pd.Series)` on each `Counter`, it converts it to a df with a column for each word and the value in that column is the count of that word in the `Text` value.

Comment: What I do is generate columns for *every* word in the `Text` values, sum the columns that are not in `wordlist` into an `other_words` column, and then drop those columns from the result.

Comment: i see, wondering if there is any way that i only count word in the list  ? e.g. ignore you from no 1

Comment: If you only want to count words in `wordlist` (and not `other_words`) then you could use `counters = df['Text'].apply(lambda t:Counter(w for w in re.findall(r'\b[a-z]+\b', t.lower()) if w in wordlist))` and ignore the last 3 lines in the answer

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative you could try this:

```
counts = (df['Text'].str.lower().str.findall(r'\b[a-z]+\b')
          .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).value_counts())
          .filter(map(str.lower, wordlist)).fillna(0))
df[counts.columns] = counts

print(df)
'''
   №                                 Text    i  love
0  1    I love you forever... other words  1.0   1.0
1  2  No , i know that you know xxx words  1.0   0.0
```